# Images slideshow looping and animated with the rotation effect

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I'm sure this exists but I don't know how it is called, so I don't succeed at finding it on the internet.

I'm trying to do an image presenter which can loop with a rotate effect, very similar to what you can find in video games such as the good old tomb raider 2 menu for example:

[image]

When you press left or right arrow, you can navigate between the items.

See that in action here: https://youtu.be/1T7ueLPuq94?t=197 (the player navigate to the left, he could have switched to more items, it rotates and loopes).

I would like to achieve that with this rotation effect and the loop with css3 and javascript. Can anybody help me with that?

I put part of my code in a pen https://codepen.io/Flaburgan/pen/jOOrEdx but I need help about the way to handle it. Should I start with nothing in my DOM and create `elements` with JS? Should I have all the nodes in my DOM as I know them from the beginning and they are not going to change? But then how do I loop back to the first elem?

Comment: Please post some HTML and CSS of your attempt. I realize you don't know what it's called, but we need some sort of minimal example that you are trying to apply this to. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you need my code to now where I am, or to understand what I'm trying to achieve? Because as I have almost no idea how to do that, my code should probably be dropped and restarted from scratch once I know how to start.

Comment: I edited the original post to add a link to a video to be more clear about what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Your question as it stands is too broad. You need to show you've tried something. I would start with the basics - put in the elements that you want loop/rotate. Setup the HTML.

Comment: I put part of my code in a pen, see my edit above. But it should probably be completely dropped and started over.

Comment: You want this: https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/gRJWqm - I think it's the 4th or 5th one down. It's called a 3d carousel.